# Function only runs after first dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I currently have a form that will take the dropdown selection in `rebates.php` and use an Ajax function that sends it to `update.php` which will display table data based on queries that are run using the dropdown selection. The form has an `action=""` so the page does not actually reload.

I will be having multiple tables displayed on my webpage. However, some table `tds` may be empty so I want to hide those tables. Currently, I have a function in my `update.php` page that will hide any empty `td` tables. However, that only works on the first dropdown selection. If I select another item from my dropdown that contains empty `td` tables, then those will not be hidden as this would be a second selection. How can I change this so that all empty `td` tables will be hidden no matter if it is the first selection or a second, third, etc selection?

Form/Dropdown (`rebates.php`):

```
<form name="myForm" action="">

<!-- Dropdown List -->
    <select name="master_dropdown" id="mr_id">

    <script>
    document.querySelector('#mr_id').addEventListener('change', updateSelection, false);
    document.querySelector('#mr_id').addEventListener('change', updateSelection, false);

    function updateSelection(event) {

    updatetable(this.form);
    }
    </script>

    <option selected value="select">Choose a Master Supplier Title</option>
        <?php foreach($master_supp->fetchAll() as $master) { ?>
            <option data-name="<?php echo $master['Supplier_Group_Name'];?>">
                <?php echo $master ['Supplier_Group_Name'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Javascript (`rebates.js`):

```
// Reads what the user selects from the drop down list and displays table when a selection is made
function updatetable(myForm) {   

    var selIndex = myForm.selectedIndex;
    console.log();
    var selName = $( "#mr_id option:selected" ).text().trim();
    console.log(selName);

$.ajax ({
    url: "update.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        mr_id : selName
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(".table_div").html(data);
    }
 });

}
```

Javascript inside `head` tag in `update.php`:

```
<script>
    $('table').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('tr').children("td").length < 1) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
</script>
```

I have left out the queries and tables themselves as I don't think they should be needed to answer this question. However, if they would be helpful I can post them. I assume I can just use the general `table` identifier in the function and not a specific `class` or `id`.

Comment: Why Not `var selName = $( "#mr_id" ).text().trim();` ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to refresh your view after the AJAX call. In other words, you have to run your `$('table').each(function() {...}` code every time the AJAX call is a success. Try including that after the `$(".table_div").html(data)` line in your AJAX success call.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata Hey, this works great! Put it as an answer and I will mark it as the correct one! I figured it was an easy fix, just needed a little direction...thanks

Comment: @Rataiczak24 I just did, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to refresh your view after the AJAX call. In other words, you have to run your `$('table').each(function() {...}` code every time the AJAX call is a success. Try including that after the `$(".table_div").html(data)` line in your AJAX success call.